# Is it possible to convert text images into a text file? JAVA

Tags: java, ocr

Is it possible to convert text images into a text file?

What could be the right algorithm for making this thoughts possible?

I'm new about this stuff, and I want to expand more my learning about this thing because I'm still a student.

Comment: Is it possible, yes, is it easy no.  Do search for "OCR and Java", there are some libraries around, but as to how functional they are is another issue altogether...

Comment: Have a look at j4l or tesseract

Answer (score 4):

I use `mseOCR`. I will share my example for reference. For more details is [here](https://github.com/KipkoTheGuru/OCR-Plugins/blob/master/awt/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/javaocr/ocrPlugins/mseOCR/OCRScanner.java).

Let's start to scan the following image. The image file have all most of the characters. Make sure to add `ascii.png` to classpath.

ascii.png

[image]

ImageScanner.java

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.CharacterRange;
import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.OCRScanner;
import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.TrainingImage;
import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.TrainingImageLoader;
import net.sourceforge.javaocr.scanner.PixelImage;

public class ImageScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        OCRScanner scanner = new OCRScanner();
        TrainingImageLoader loader = new TrainingImageLoader();
        HashMap<Character, ArrayList<TrainingImage>> trainingImageMap = new HashMap<Character, ArrayList<TrainingImage>>();
        loader.load("ascii.png", new CharacterRange('!', '~'), trainingImageMap);
        scanner.addTrainingImages(trainingImageMap);

        Image image = ImageIO.read(new File("ascii.png"));
        PixelImage pixelImage = new PixelImage(image);
        pixelImage.toGrayScale(true);
        pixelImage.filter();

        String text = scanner.scan(image, 0, 0, 0, 0, null);
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Output

```
!"#$%&' ()*+,-
./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
PQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv
wxyz{ | }~
```

Library

```
javaocr-core-1.0.jar    
javaocr-plugin-awt-1.0.jar
javaocr-plugin-cluster-1.0.jar
javaocr-plugin-fir-1.0.jar
javaocr-plugin-moment-1.0.jar
javaocr-plugin-morphology-1.0.jar
```

Comment: About this library,
`import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.CharacterRange;`
`import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.OCRScanner;`
`import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.TrainingImage;`
`import net.sourceforge.javaocr.ocrPlugins.mseOCR.TrainingImageLoader;`
`import net.sourceforge.javaocr.scanner.PixelImage;`

How can I find or add it on my java sdk library? or do I have to download it first?

Comment: download it first, add this lib in your classpath

Comment: I am using eclipse IE.. ..but i still don't know how to configure it.. can you help me to add this plugins?